# calculating total progress of downloading multiple file with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, afnetworking

I want to download multiple file and then display a total progress to the user.

but the problem is here I dont know how should I calculate total progress .

here is what I do:
first I get to totalBytes Expected to receive from all of the files:

```
for (NSURL candidateUrl in UrlsList)
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:candidateURL];
                        //setting HTTPMethod of request from GET to HEAD to download header files of requests, so we can get file size before downloaing file
                        [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

                        getTotalImagesBytesOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
                        [getTotalImagesBytesOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                         {
                             //setting totalImagesBytesExpectedToRead of all images. we use it to know how many bytes we should download for all the images
                              totalImagesBytesExpectedToRead += [operation.response expectedContentLength];


                         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                         }];

                        [operationQueue addOperation:getTotalImagesBytesOperation];
}
```

after estimating total files size:

```
        //downloading images
    for (NSURL *imageUrl in imagesURLList) {
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl];
        AFImageRequestOperation *downloadImageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                  imageProcessingBlock:nil

                                                                                               success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {                                                                                      
NSLog(@"success")
}
failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                       NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                                                                   }];

        [operationQueue addOperation:downloadImageOperation];

        [downloadImageOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
        {

          **HOW TO CALCULATE TOTAL PROGRESS**
}
```

I don't know how to calculate total size!!
the values we have: 
totalBytesOfAllTheFiles, totalBytesRead and totalBytesExpectedToRead for the current file which above method gives you, indexOfCurrentFile and countOfFiles.

be cautious setDownloadProgressBlock called hundreds a time.

does anyone have any idea? (sorry for bad formatting of code!)

Comment: Wouldn't you just divide `totalBytesRead` by `totalBytesExpectedToRead`?

Comment: @evan.stoddard `totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead` gives me the percent completion  of current file. not the whole files!

Comment: First consideration: do you really need to be so precise to use total bytes to calculate the progress? I used "total files downloaded" / "total files to be downloaded" to calculate the progress for an app. It's a lot easier.

Comment: Think about when your first five files are total 1 mb and last five files are 100 mb. that calculation is not good.

Comment: In that case, the only way may be to read the "total size" information from a data file somewhere on the network before the downloading starts. If that is not possible, you have to re-think through your app design. You can't know the size of all files before you download them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I achieved that:
first create an NSOperationQueue:

```
// Add the operation to a queue
// It will start once added
//calculating images byte size
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
foreach (NSURL *candidateURL in urlList )
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:candidateURL];
                    //setting HTTPMethod of request from GET to HEAD to download header files of requests, so we can get file size before downloaing file
                    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

                    AFHTTPRequestOperation *getTotalImagesBytesOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
                    [getTotalImagesBytesOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                     {
                         //setting totalImagesBytesExpectedToRead of all images. we use it to know how many bytes we should download for all the images
                         totalImagesBytesExpectedToRead += [operation.response expectedContentLength];


                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                     }];

                    [operationQueue addOperation:getTotalImagesBytesOperation];
}

 //downloading images which should be downloaded
for (NSURL *imageUrl in imagesShouldBeDownlaoded) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadFileOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    //we must provide file path with file name and its extension
    NSString *fileName = [self getImageName:[imageUrl absoluteString]];
    downloadFileOperation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[[ImageManager applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] append:NO];

    [downloadFileOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id response)
     {
         NSLog(@"file saved");

     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         completionBlock(NO, error);
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }];

    [operationQueue addOperation:downloadFileOperation];

    [downloadFileOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
     {
         totalBytesDownloaded += bytesRead;

         //total progress from 0.0 to 1.0
         progress = ((float)totalBytesDownloaded/(float)totalImagesBytesExpectedToRead);
         if(progress == 1)
         {
             completionBlock(YES, nil);
         }
         progressCallback(progress);
    }];
```

operationQueue works as a FIFO list, first calculate images byte size, then starts to download all images

Comment: please explain the use of completionBlock and progressCallback. Also where do you start the operation like [downloadFileOperation Start]. Please do comment. I am bit stuck here.

Comment: there is no need to start operation explicitly, download operation will be started implicitly by adding operation to the operation Queue. also completionBlock and progressCallback are my custom blocks which will notify me about download progress or download failure or success.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking3 use `dispatch_group` and `NSProgress` to achieved this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking.h>

@interface Server : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPSessionManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSProgress *progress;

- (void)downloadFilesWithUrls:(NSMutableArray <NSURL *>*)urls;

@end



#import "Server.h"
@implementation Server

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        _manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        _manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        _progress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:0];
        [_progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"fractionCompleted:%lf",self.progress.fractionCompleted);
}

- (void)downloadFilesWithUrls:(NSMutableArray <NSURL *>*)urls {
    //progress
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    _progress.totalUnitCount = urls.count;
    [urls enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSURL * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
         dispatch_group_enter(group);
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:obj];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [self.manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
        } destination:^NSURL * _Nonnull(NSURL * _Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response) {
            return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURL * _Nullable filePath, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"one task completion");
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];

        NSProgress *child = [self.manager downloadProgressForTask:task];
        [self.progress addChild:child withPendingUnitCount:1];
        [task resume];
    }];

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%lf", self.progress.fractionCompleted);
    });

}

@end
```